# Imprecise TEXCOORD interpolation of a screen quad in DirectX

Tags: rendering, interpolation, directx12, directx11

I was debugging with RenderDoc an issue on an app based on Directx11 and 12 that draw screen space quads to perform various baking steps. These baking steps just render a quad in clip space without any transformation with two triangles and the interpolated texture coordinates (TEXCOORD0) of the 4 vertices (which are then used in the pixel shader) are set to (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0).

[image]

In the pixel shader, checking these coordinates in the (0, 0) pixel, I expect to see the coordinates of the center of that pixel, but the values are slightly off:

[image]
[image]

With a 17x17 viewport, I was expecting to see both (x, y) at 1 / (2 * 17) = (0.0294117647, 0.0294117647) but as you see I get (0.0294118524, 0.029411763). I see this on any coordinate and both in dx11 and 12. The error is small, but well above the float precision, is this normal or am I missing something?